# Storing HTML in a Twig Array

Tags: php, html, arrays, twig

Ok I'm trying to add HTML code to a Twig array and ending up into problems. I'm not the most knowledgable when it comes to Twig so I'll need help. I'm getting this error when I try:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Twig_Error_Syntax: Arguments must be separated by a comma.
```

What am I doing wrong? https://pastebin.com/gEGLnCid 

`{% set myArray= [] %}
{% for product in products %}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to do it in two steps e.g.

```
{% set arr = [] %}
{% for i in 1..10 %}
    {% set foo %}
        {{ i * 10 }}
        foo
        bar
        foobar
        {{ i  }}
    {% endset %}
    {% set arr = arr | merge([ foo, ]) %}
{% endfor %}

{% for val in arr %}
    {{ val }}
{% endfor %}
```